# Ngb datepicker inline support for container body

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, ngb-datepicker

I am using ndbdatepicker inline and i am forced to used it as my old functionality is having to many work which i cant change and so i need a support for container body as we have this in case of ngbInputDatepicker any solution ?